# How does one interpret sklearn sparse matrix outputs?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sparse-matrix

I am trying to produce a bigram word co-occurrence matrix, indicating how many times one word follows another in a corpus.

As a test, I wrote the following (which I gathered from other SE questions):

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

test_sent = ['hello', 'i', 'am', 'hello', 'i', 'dont', 'want', 'to', 'i', 'dont']
bigram_vec = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,2)) 
X = bigram_vec.fit_transform(test_sent)
Xc = (X.T * X)
print Xc
```

This should give the correct output. The matrix `Xc` is output like so:

```
(0, 0)  1
(1, 1)  2
(2, 2)  2
(3, 3)  1
(4, 4)  1
```

I have no idea how to interpret this. I attempted to make it dense to help with my interpretation using `Xc.todense()`, which got this:

```
[[1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 2 0 0 0]
 [0 0 2 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1]]
```

Neither of these give the correct word co-occurrence matrix showing one how many times row follows column.

Could someone please explain how I can interpret/use the output? Why is it like that?

**Addition to question**

Here is another possible output with a different example using `ngram_range=(2,2)`:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

test_sent = ['hello biggest awesome biggest biggest awesome today lively splendid awesome today']

bigram_vec = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(2,2)) 

X = bigram_vec.fit_transform(test_sent)
print bigram_vec.get_feature_names()

Xc = (X.T * X)

print Xc
print ' '
print Xc.todense()

(4, 0)  1
(2, 0)  2
(0, 0)  1
(3, 0)  1
(1, 0)  2
(7, 0)  1
(5, 0)  1
(6, 0)  1
(4, 1)  2
(2, 1)  4
(0, 1)  2
(3, 1)  2
(1, 1)  4
(7, 1)  2
(5, 1)  2
(6, 1)  2
(4, 2)  2
(2, 2)  4
(0, 2)  2
(3, 2)  2
(1, 2)  4
(7, 2)  2
(5, 2)  2
(6, 2)  2
(4, 3)  1
:   :
(6, 4)  1
(4, 5)  1
(2, 5)  2
(0, 5)  1
(3, 5)  1
(1, 5)  2
(7, 5)  1
(5, 5)  1
(6, 5)  1
(4, 6)  1
(2, 6)  2
(0, 6)  1
(3, 6)  1
(1, 6)  2
(7, 6)  1
(5, 6)  1
(6, 6)  1
(4, 7)  1
(2, 7)  2
(0, 7)  1
(3, 7)  1
(1, 7)  2
(7, 7)  1
(5, 7)  1
(6, 7)  1

[[1 2 2 1 1 1 1 1]
 [2 4 4 2 2 2 2 2]
 [2 4 4 2 2 2 2 2]
 [1 2 2 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 2 2 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 2 2 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 2 2 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 2 2 1 1 1 1 1]]
```

This one seems to tokenize by bigrams, since calling `bigram_vec.get_feature_names()` gives

```
[u'awesome biggest', u'awesome today', u'biggest awesome', u'biggest biggest', u'hello biggest', u'lively splendid', u'splendid awesome', u'today lively']
```

Some help interpretting this would be great. It's a symmetric matrix so I'm thinking it might just be number of occurrences?

Comment: Yes you are right. Its showing the number of occurences of each bigram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to check out the feature names which the CountVectorizer is using.

Do this:

```
bigram_vec.get_feature_names()
# Out:  [u'am', u'dont', u'hello', u'to', u'want']
```

You see that the word `"i"` is not present. That's because the default tokenizer uses a pattern:

> token_pattern : string
>
> ```
> Regular expression denoting what constitutes a “token”, only used if 
> analyzer == 'word'. The default regexp select tokens of 2 or more
> alphanumeric characters (punctuation is completely ignored and always
> treated as a token separator).
> ```

And the actual output of the X should be interpreted as:

```
            [u'am', u'dont', u'hello', u'to', u'want']
'hello'    [[ 0        0        1        0       0]
'i'         [ 0        0        0        0       0]
'am'        [ 1        0        0        0       0]
'hello'     [ 0        0        1        0       0]
'i'         [ 0        0        0        0       0]
'dont'      [ 0        1        0        0       0]
'want'      [ 0        0        0        0       1]
'to'        [ 0        0        0        1       0]
'i'         [ 0        0        0        0       0]
'dont'      [ 0        1        0        0       0]]
```

Now when you do `X.T * X` this should be interpreted as:

```
           u'am'  u'dont'  u'hello'  u'to'  u'want'
u'am'      [[1      0         0        0       0]
u'dont'     [0      2         0        0       0]
u'hello'    [0      0         2        0       0]
u'to'       [0      0         0        1       0]
u'want'     [0      0         0        0       1]]
```

If you are expecting anything else, then you should add the details in the question.

Comment: OK, so it seems like X.T*X is the format I am looking for. But it's just telling me how many times each word appears (e.g. 2 in dont,dont; 1 in to,to). So your answer does actually answer my question. Do you know how I can get it into the format I want? Where it shows how many times one word follows another in the bigrams?

Comment: I also added another example with a slightly different ngram_range argument